# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de pasar parámetros a método get en webapi mediante $.getJSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, razor

Buenas tengo una duda de como hacer esto de la mejor manera:

Tengo un método `GET` en mi `controller` que recibe 3 parámetros:

```
    [Route("api/Visita/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}")]
    public Visita Get(short idCompania, short idLocal, string fecha)
```

En mi vista tengo estos parámetros disponibles en mi `ViewBag`, ¿hay alguna forma limpia de pasarlos como parámetros a `$.getJSON` para que él se encargue de ejecutar la llamada a mi método [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) ?

¿debería ubicaros en como `hidden` para obtenerlos mediante `$("#idLocal").val()` por ejemplo?

Solo puedo interactuar con objetos del `DOM` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los datos estan en el ViewBag y no van a cambiar podrias asignarlo a variables que arma el json.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      var params= {
         idCompania: '@ViewBag.idCompania',
         idLocal: '@ViewBag.idLocal',
         fecha: '@ViewBag.fecha'
      };

      $.getJSON('api/Visita', params, function(data){ 
           //codigo
      });
   });
</script>
```

Como veras armas el json que enviarias como data del $.getJSON

---

Si el codigo cliente esta en un .js separado en la view defines las lineas

```
 <script>
   var idCompania= '@ViewBag.idCompania';
   var idLocal= '@ViewBag.idLocal';
   var fecha= '@ViewBag.fecha';
</script>
```

entonces dentro del .js simplemente accedes a las variables ya que estas son globales

Comment: muy buena, ¿pero esto funciona fuera del `cshtml` ? tengo entendido que no.

Comment: claro, el codigo que puse es jquery, ejecuta del lado del cliente. El cshtml es la view del lado del servidor cuando aun no se renderiza

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices @LeandroTuttini  a lo que me refiero es que en un script el `ViewBag` no lo toma, osea no obtiene el valor ya que no es parte del `script` sino de la vista.

Comment: Pero en algun momento la vista se renderiza, y es alli cuando se genera el script que se envia al cliente. Al momento del render unira los datos del viewbag con el cshtml de la view (que tendra el script) y lo enviara al cliente. Si el Action envia los datos en el viewbag a la view deberia asignarse esto en el script

Comment: lo que quiero decirte es que esto no está funcionando, no reconoce viewbag dentro del script, no lo está reemplazando por los respectivos valores que contiene.

Comment: @Alan Lo que Leandro al parecer quizo explicar es que tu script debe estar incluido dentro de la vista en el fichero cshtml como un script inline no como un fichero separado. El razor es lo suficientemente inteligente como para ver el símbolo @ y reemplazar el valor correspondiente suponiendo que haya uno

Comment: Claro a eso es a lo que me refería con _solo funciona dentro de la vista_  y no renderizandolo con Scripts.Render. Quizá no quedó claro, pero en fin es una buena respuesta, gracias @devconcept

Comment: el codigo cliente lo tienes dentro de un .js? si es asi entonces edito la respuesta agregando una extension

Comment: Acoto algo... @Alan esta utilizando atributo de ruta y definió de esta manera la ruta/url de la api "api/Visita/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}" por lo cual deberia "armar manualmente" la cadena de laurl y no pasar los parametros como simple param del metodo getJSON

Comment: @Jose, pero no seria indistinto, hasta donde tengo entendido los valores de la url son opcionales, Model Binding cuando mapea los datos que les llega no tomaria los de la url o del cuerdo del mensajes? Lo que habria que ver es como el $.getJSON() envia por GET los datos al action del webapi

Comment: mientras pueda armar la URL como comenta @JoseA.Fernandez esta genial.

Comment: No puedo asegurarlo, pero el $.getJSON() esta indicando que realiza el pedido por GET, por lo tanto si defines datos en json va a mapear estos en la url

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas utilizar campos hidden, podrías utilizar la URL del navegador para obtenerlos (ya que están disponibles en la ruta):

```
var datos = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var idCompania = datos[datos.length - 3];
var idLocal = datos[datos.length - 2];
var fecha = datos[datos.length - 1];
```

Claro que esta es una solución *solo javascript*.